# character value comparison between columns with condition in r

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as:

```
 mi chr gen.pos phys.pos    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4
 snp1   Ch09    NA  12712760    CC  CC  CT  TT
 snp3   Ch02    NA  16594215    GG  HH  GG  GG
 snp6   Ch14    NA  34284723    CC  --  CC  TT
 snp7   Ch13    NA  21532194    AA  GG  AA  GG
 snp8   Ch13    NA  21532040    CC  AA  CC  AA
 snp9   Ch11    NA  38423068    TT  CT  CC  CC
```

I would like to create another three columns to hold the result of comparisons between `sample4` to other three samples, with a condition: only any two values from the list `c("AA","CC","GG","TT","HH")` are compared, the return value is `TRUE`, otherwise, `FALSE`. So the expected result is:

```
 mi chr gen.pos phys.pos    sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample4_sample1 sample4_sample2 sample4_sample3
 snp1   Ch09    NA  12712760    CC  CC  CT  TT  TRUE    TRUE    FALSE
 snp3   Ch02    NA  16594215    GG  HH  GG  GG  FALSE   TRUE    FALSE
 snp6   Ch14    NA  34284723    CC  --  CC  TT  TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
 snp7   Ch13    NA  21532194    AA  GG  AA  GG  TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
 snp8   Ch13    NA  21532040    CC  AA  CC  AA  TRUE    FALSE   TRUE
 snp9   Ch11    NA  38423068    TT  CT  CC  CC  TRUE    FALSE   FALSE
```

Thanks for helps.

Comment: @akun if the same values compared, "FALSE" value would be assigned. Basically, I just want to subset three data frames from the `df` based on the last three columns as index,respectively, only take rows with different "homo" values.

Comment: Thanks, I did assumed that would be the case.  Could you please check the solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try

```
Un <-  c("AA","CC","GG","TT","HH")
newCols <- paste(colnames(df)[8], colnames(df)[5:7], sep="_")
df[newCols] <-  Map(function(x,y,z) x!=y &
                    apply(cbind(x,y), 1, FUN=function(.x) all(.x %in% z)),
                      df[paste0('sample', 1:3)],  df['sample4'], list(Un))

df
#    mi  chr gen.pos phys.pos sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample4_sample1
#1 snp1 Ch09      NA 12712760      CC      CC      CT      TT            TRUE
#2 snp3 Ch02      NA 16594215      GG      HH      GG      GG           FALSE
#3 snp6 Ch14      NA 34284723      CC      --      CC      TT            TRUE
#4 snp7 Ch13      NA 21532194      AA      GG      AA      GG            TRUE
#5 snp8 Ch13      NA 21532040      CC      AA      CC      AA            TRUE
#6 snp9 Ch11      NA 38423068      TT      CT      CC      CC            TRUE
#  sample4_sample2 sample4_sample3
#1            TRUE           FALSE
#2            TRUE           FALSE
#3           FALSE            TRUE
#4           FALSE            TRUE
#5           FALSE            TRUE
#6           FALSE           FALSE
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(mi = c("snp1", "snp3", "snp6", "snp7", "snp8", 
"snp9"), chr = c("Ch09", "Ch02", "Ch14", "Ch13", "Ch13", "Ch11"
), gen.pos = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), phys.pos = c(12712760L, 
16594215L, 34284723L, 21532194L, 21532040L, 38423068L), sample1 = c("CC", 
"GG", "CC", "AA", "CC", "TT"), sample2 = c("CC", "HH", "--", 
"GG", "AA", "CT"), sample3 = c("CT", "GG", "CC", "AA", "CC", 
"CC"), sample4 = c("TT", "GG", "TT", "GG", "AA", "CC")), .Names = c("mi", 
"chr", "gen.pos", "phys.pos", "sample1", "sample2", "sample3", 
"sample4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: your simple solution is impressive with `Map` function. I just made a little bit of modification: assign `colnames(df)[8]` and `colnames(df)[5:7]` to two variables respectively, then use variable names in the line 2 and line 5. So this code can work on any column against other columns, if you define the two variables in advance. Thank you so much.